# string buffer java.lang.CharSequence error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, stringbuffer

I'am working with spring hibernate maven in eclipse ide .

when I use `StringBuffer` I am getting the error:

> The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Example code:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("some string");
```

The error is showing in append code line.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: It's clear that some class path issue. Nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: how can i resolve this? I have added the dependencies by configure build path. but still error . please help.

Comment: have you added multiple jre's or jdk's to your classpath ? or  added a difference jre and jdk ? cna you please sohw the classpath diagram ?

Comment: no just jdk1.8. Only string buffer has got error everything else works fine

Comment: Try to clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: you can also visit this link http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/bugs/944/

Comment: @jens, ok let me try.

Comment: clean and build is not working ..

Comment: @KevalTrivedi That link has got the same problem that i have , But no solution in it.

Comment: @vipincp please visit link properly.Solution is at the end of the page.

Comment: @vipincp also visit this link : http://dev-answers.blogspot.de/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html

Comment: Thanks for all for the reply.

Comment: is it working properly ?

Comment: Now it is.. I dont know how, i just cleaned the target folder of maven and redeploy it. It works..